# Can I emulate arrow key in sublimetext3?

Tags: sublimetext3, ime

In short:
I want to type [left arrow], [right arrow], [command-v] sequence whenever I press [command-v] in sublime text 3.

In length: I have a problem with IME and pasting in sublime text (OSX). If you don't use asian language you might not understand what I'm saying but let me try.

I'm korean. My language has letters like '각' and '가'. Do you notice the difference? The prior letter have additional 'ㄱ' at its bottom.

To type in those letters, you press 'ㄱ' -> 'ㅏ' -> 'ㄱ' for prior, and 'ㄱ' -> 'ㅏ' for latter. Again, do you notice the difference?

To complete the letter '각', you should make the letter '가' first, and type in additional 'ㄱ'. However, you want '가' this time, so typed 'ㄱ' -> 'ㅏ' and **completed the letter '가'**, but sublime (or OSX IME) doesn't know whether you completed, or **should wait for the additional ㄱ to complete the letter '각'**. So it awaits next type to decide to start new letter, or to complete something like '각'. My problem begins here.

You completed the letter and want to paste something, so press [command-v], but sublime was waiting for additional component and **did not finish the letter**. It just **deletes** the letter '가'. To work around this problem, I type in something like [space] or [arrow key] to make sure sublime completes the letter. This is fairly annoying.

So, I want to automate the annoying potion. Can I type [left arrow], [right arrow], [command-v] sequence whenever I press [command-v] in sublime text 3? [space], [backspace], [command-v] or any combination will work, I think.

Any help will be highly appreiciated

Comment: In case you wonder, Windows IME is better than OSX when it comes to pasting something. Windows completes the letter whenever you press [Ctrl-v] so this problem never happen. However, sublime in Windows have a bigger, ugly problem than can't work around :(

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution to your dilemma could be to create a macro. To do this, look in `Tools -> Record Macro`, which you'll also notice is triggered by `Ctrl + Q`. Once you activate that, perform the key combination you wish to invoke. In this case, the sequence:

- `Left Arrow`
- `Right Arrow`
- `Ctrl + V`

Now go back into `Tools -> Stop Recording Macro`. Now, it won't be explicitly saved yet - your macro is now placed on the buffer, and you can play it back with `Tools -> Playback Macro`. To save it for continued use, use `Tools -> Save Macro...` and save it somewhere (most commonly in `.../Packages/User`, although by no means do you **need** to save it here).

For reference sake, your macro should look exactly like this:

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "characters",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "characters",
            "forward": true
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "paste"
    }
]
```

That text was generated by following my steps exactly and recording the macro appropriate to your situation.

And to *use* this macro, we'll need to do a little more tinkering.

Look in `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`. This will open a rather derelict text file (assuming you haven't touched it yet) where you can specify your own keyboard mappings. These will override the default settings (located in `Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default`, if you wish to check those out).

So in this "User" key bindings file, we need to specify that the normal `Ctrl + V` will be overridden by our custom macro. An empty "User" key bindings file will look like this:

```
[

]
```

Not much to extrapolate from. The syntax required here is fairly legible, but pretty difficult to guess at without prior knowledge. Add this entry between those brackets, like so:

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+v"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "path/to/your/<macro_name>.sublime-macro"}
    }
]
```

Save that file, and you should be good to go. You may need to restart Sublime for this to take effect.